# Is possible to inserted images inside string to align center height with image?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is possible to inserted images inside string to align center height with image ?
I have long text and it is shown in one TextView in couple lines and I need to insert image but Image has height bigger than font size and I need to in line where is inserted image be align by height (at the moment image is inserted with characters bottom line)

```
SpannableString text = new SpannableString(getString("Help something about paragraph"));
text.setSpan(new ImageSpan(myIcon, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE), text.length()- 9, text.length()- 8, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
txtGetHelp.setText(text);
```

With this is is aligned by baseline and I didn't find option to align center by height image and text. It should be like this

[image]

Comment: Create a horizontal orientated LinearLayout, place both Imageview and TextView in it and give gravity="center_vertical"

Comment: @A.S. But I don't know size of text and where to put, I need to do this programatically, image is inserted somewhere in text, with linear  layout it would be whole text centered with image but I need one line to be centered with image

Comment: @Damir : Do you mean you want all text to wrap around a centre image? In other words above the image then to the sides and then below?

Comment: @Squonk I have edited a little question, I hope I clarify a little